# Product added to the Catalog collection does not display a price

Tags: magento2, product, price, catalog

I created a preference for the block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` to add a specific product at the begining of the collection in `getLoadedProductCollection()`. Almost everything is well displayed except the price.

```php
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $originalCollection= parent::getLoadedProductCollection();
        $featuredProduct = $this->productFactory->create()->load(18); //test productId
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() !== 'catalogsearch_result_index' || !$featuredProduct) {
            return $originalCollection;
        }

        $newCollection = clone $originalCollection;
        $newCollection->removeAllItems();

        try {
            if($featuredProduct->getId()) {
                $newCollection->addItem($featuredProduct);
            }
            foreach ($originalCollection as $item) {
                if ($item->getId() != $featuredProduct->getId()) {
                    $newCollection->addItem($item);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception) {}
        return $newCollection;
    }
```

I'm not sure why in `list.phtml`, `$block->getProductPrice($_product)` return an empty string only for this product. The rest of the catalog is working normally.